# I am not getting the value of iframe after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a google map, which loads as an iframe. I want to modify the place name after it loads, but somewhere I am missing, here is my jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#gmap_canvas').load(function() {
          const place = $("#gmap_canvas").contents().find(".place-name").text(); 
          console.log(place);   
        });
    })
```

I have also tried with iframe as selector, I have iframe id as gmap_canvas. It's not working for me. The content with class name is "place-name"

Comment: I'm guessing the "Same Origin Policy" is blocking you from accessing the contents of the iFrame.

Comment: Okay, what can I do to manipulate the values. However those values are accessible through console, but after clicking to map using developer tool. Initially it is null. But after clicking the map using tool and then checking it using console, gives the correct value.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there may be something in the Maps API that lets you do this.